# google maps and ajax

Tags: jquery-plugins, google-fusion-tables

Is it possible to return a variable, more specifically an array of values or a string from an $.ajax call. I currently understand that this can't be done... i.e. $.ajax responses need to be added to the DOM immediately. Please correct me if I am missing something obvious here.

```
var infoWindow;
var tableID = 'atableID';    
var str;



var beachID;
var beach_location;
var beach_region;

/* start map initialization  */
function initialize() {
latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.894634, -97.119141);
var myOptions = {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [
                                        google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                                        google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                                        google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                                        google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                                    ],

        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    overviewMapControl: true,
    overviewMapControlOptions: {
        opened: true
    }
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: 'Point',
        from: atableID
    },
    suppressInfoWindows: true
});
layer.setMap(map);
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function (e) {


    // close infoWindow if open
    if (infoWindow) {
        infoWindow.close();
    }
    beachID = e.row['Beach_ID'].value;
    beach_location = e.row['Beach_Location'].value; ;
    beach_region = e.row['Beach_Region'].value;;

    //console.log(beachID);

    // get data set
    getEcoliData(beachID,beach_location,beach_region);
    getAlgaeData(beachID,beach_location,beach_region);


});           // end google.maps.addListener
} // end map initialization

function getEcoliData(beachID,beach_location,beach_region) {
//local namespace
var rows = [];
var ecoliTable;

var items = [];

var queryURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=";
var queryTail = '&key=a key value=?';
var whereClause = "WHERE 'Beach_ID' = " + beachID;
var query = "SELECT 'Sample_Date',   'Average_E._coli_Density','Recreational_Water_Quality_Guideline' FROM atblid " + whereClause + " ORDER BY 'Sample_Date' DESC";
var queryText = encodeURI(query);



    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: queryURL + queryText + queryTail,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        rows = data.rows;

        // empty table
        //$('#content_placeholder').empty();
        //$('.ecoli_table').remove();

        $('#ecoli_heading').empty();

        $('#content_placeholder').prepend('<h6 id="ecoli_heading">E.Coli Data</h6>')
            .append('<p>' + beach_location + '</p>').append('<p>' + beach_region + '</p>');
        $('.ecoli_table').append('<tr>'
                                 + '<th>Sample Date</th>'
                                 + '<th>Average E.Coli Density</th>'
                                 + '<th>Recreational Water Quality Guideline</th>'
                                 + '</tr>');
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            //items.push(rows[i]);
            $('.ecoli_table tr:first').after('<tr><td>' + rows[i].join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>');
        }
        if (typeof ecoliTable == 'undefined') {
            // dataTables
            ecoliTable = $(".ecoli_table").dataTable({
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
                "bDestroy": true,
                "aoColumns": [
                                                    { "sTitle": "Sample_Date" },
                                                    { "sTitle": "Average_E._coli_Density" },
                                                    { "sTitle": "Recreational_Water_Quality_Guideline" }
                                            ]
            });
        } else {
            //ecoliTable.fnDestroy();
            $(".ecoli_table > tbody").empty();
            ecoliTable.fnDraw();
            //$('.ecoli_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Data is not available for this location at the present time, please check back at a later time. Thank you.");
    }
});
}


function getAlgaeData(beachID,beach_location,beach,region) {
//local namespace
var rows = [];
var algaeTable;

var items = [];

var queryURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=";
var queryTail = '&key=apikey&callback=?';
var whereClause = "WHERE 'Beach_ID' = " + beachID;
var query = "SELECT 'Sample_Date','Algal_Toxin_Microcystin','Recreational_Guideline_20','Blue_Green_Algae_Cells','Recreational_Guideline' FROM tableid " + whereClause + " ORDER BY 'Sample_Date' DESC";
var queryText = encodeURI(query);



$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: queryURL + queryText + queryTail,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        rows = data.rows;

        // empty table
        //$('#content_placeholder').empty();
        //$('.algae_table').remove();

        $('#algae_heading').empty();
        $('.ecoli_table').after('<h6 id="algae_heading">Algae Data</h6>');
        $('.algae_table').append('<tr>'
                                 + '<th>Sample Date</th>'
                                 + '<th>Algal_Toxin_Microcystin</th>'
                                 + '<th>Recreational_Guideline_20</th>'
                                 + '<th>Blue_Green_Algae_Cells</th>'
                                 + '<th>Recreational_Guideline</th>'
                                 + '</tr>');
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            //items.push(rows[i]);
            $('.algae_table tr:first').after('<tr><td>' + rows[i].join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>');
        }
        if (typeof algaeTable == 'undefined') {
            //algae
            algaeTable = $(".algae_table").dataTable({
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "bDestroy": true,
                "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],

                "aoColumns": [
                                                            { "sTitle": "Sample_Date" },
                                                            { "sTitle": "Algal_Toxin_Microcystin" },
                                                            { "sTitle": "Recreational_Guideline_20" },
                                                            { "sTitle": "Blue_Green_Algae_Cells" },
                                                             { "sTitle": "Recreational_Guideline" }
                                                    ]
            });
        } else {
            //algaeTable.fnDestroy();  
            $(".algae_table > tbody").empty();
            algaeTable.fnDraw();
            //$('.algae_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        }


    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Data is not available for this location at the present time, please check back at a later time. Thank you.");
    }
});
}
```

I am trying to query 2 different Google Fusion tables and return each table under a new tab within a google infoWindow. However, I am running into issues because I can't seem to return an array or string from the $.ajax function to the parent scope. For example, the items array above returns undefined. Any thoughts around this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. You haven't provided enough code to determine what's wrong, e.g. queryURL, queryText, etc.  You'll need your Google API key as well.  Here is an example demonstrating how to do it.

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/basic_jsonp_request

Comment: I included the JQuery dataTable plugin into the mix. I now need a way to either remove the entire datatable or a way to remove all rows before a new table is drawn. I then want to add the two dataTables into a tabbed Google infoWindow - not sure what my next steps are in terms of writing  the proper syntax? Any suggestions as welcomed and encouraged. Thanks in advance, Michael

Comment: Never used the dataTable plugin. Your code seems a mixture of things. The docs http://www.datatables.net/api mention: fnClearTable(), etc.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I managed to get the dataTable into the google InfoWindow, but now I am having issues resizing the datatable to adjust to the width of the google infoWindow. I will keep you posted. Thanks again,